# enter mathematical formulas in html textbox and storing it to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, math

I need to display mathematical formulas in text input and store it in database

formulas like given in below image
http://xahlee.info/math/i/math_formula_MathJax.png

when i copy any formula to text box it's converted to normal text, i need to disaplay formula as it is.

Comment: Honestly wondering, is this even (possible in) HTML?

Comment: Are you copying the actual characters or images? If they are characters they should go in fine. You'll need to escape when outputting them back.

Comment: it is not possible in html. i am looking for some js library or something to do the job

Comment: i am copying actual text formulas but symbols like under root, summation etc. got removed from it.

Comment: Requests for 3rd-party libraries is off-topic here, but maybe check out [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Comment: Why you not trying some js editor to remove this problem ? @ParthGundania

Answer (score 0):

There are [HTML characters for mathematical symbols](http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html), but to organise them similar to your image is not possible using plain HTML.

You could have a look into using the HTML [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) with JavaScript to create the result you need. You could even store the JavaScript in your MySQL Database.

Small example using your image as reference:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// k above sigma
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("k", 20, 20);

// sigma
ctx.font = "40px Arial";
ctx.fillText("\u03A3", 10, 55);

// n=1 below sigma
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("n=1", 10, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```